# Unit Test Net core - Integration test with In memory database for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, integration-testing, asp.net-core-6.0, in-memory-database

I have a class library project to do with MongoDb. I want to write UTs to cover all functions.

I'm trying to find the way create an InMemory database for MongoDb when write Unit test in net core 6.0.

But I don't have any clue about it.

I can create InMemory database for mysql, sql. It work well. But with MongoDb, It alway use my default port 27017 on my local

Could give me the document or example?

Thanks you a lot.

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB cannot be configured as "in memory" mode on a client side. It will be client server communication in any case and a driver will always use a web socket to communicate with server. The only target you can reach is you can configure `in memory` storage [engine](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/inmemory/) on server side (also see [here](https://www.mongodb.com/databases/in-memory-database) and [here](https://www.bmc.com/blogs/mongodb-memory-usage-and-management/)) which effectively will mean that instead of storing data on a disk by server, the server will keep it in memory (and consume much more of memory as the result) but it won't give you any benefits as far as I can tell.